# Layout of the output array image is incompatible with cv::Mat (step[ndims-1] != elemsize or step[1] != elemsize*nchannels)

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, medical, image-morphology

I am trying to draw contours on a specific part of a slice of a MRI. The code is as follows:

```
epi_img = nib.load('G:\BTech Project Dataset\MICCAI_BraTS17_Data_Training\HGG\Brats17_CBICA_AAL_1\Brats17_CBICA_AAL_1_t2.nii.gz')
epi_img_data = epi_img.get_data()
slice_2 = epi_img_data[:, :, 78]

###Selection of the best region for tumor incidence
se1 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (7,7))
se2 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))

###Performing Closing Operation
closing_mask = cv2.morphologyEx(thresholded2, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, se1)
###Performing Opening Operation
opening_mask = cv2.morphologyEx(closing_mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, se2)

### find contours in the edge map
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresholded2.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]
cnts=np.array(cnts)
cv2.drawContours(slice_2,cnts, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

I referred to similar other questions here and applied their suggested solution as well.
Still, I keep getting the same error

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: you should at least say the shape of slice_2 and dtype...

Comment: When you use cv2 functions, please change image type to 'uint8'